# Calculated sequence in list

Tags: python

I would like to put the sequence of same number in list to finally caculated the length of each sequence.

```
l= []
h = ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1']
for i in h:
if i == "1":
 l.append([i])
elif i == "0":
l.append(i)
```

Output :

```
[['1'], ['1'], '0', ['1'], ['1'], ['1']
```

Output that i would like:

```
[['1', '1'], '0', ['1', '1', '1']
```

Thanks

Comment: Check out `itertools.groupby`; e.g. `[list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(h)]`.

Answer (score 2):

if you find a 1 there can be two options:

-the previous element was 0, so you need to append a new list containing 1.

-the previous element was a 1, so you need to extend an existing list addion a 1

Of course you can only check for previous element if the index `i` is greater than 0.

```
l= []
h = ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1']
for i, elem in enumerate(h):        
    if elem == "0":
        l.append("0")
    elif elem == "1" and i > 0 and l[-1] != "0":
        l[-1].extend("1")
    else:
        l.append(["1"])
print(l)

[['1', '1'], '0', ['1', '1', '1']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

The code converts the content of the group to a list. If this list has more than one entry this list will be added to the resulting list. If there is only one entry just this entry is added.

```
import itertools

h = ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1']
l = [elements[0] if len(elements) == 1 else elements for elements in (list(group) for _, group in itertools.groupby(h))]
print(l)
```

The result is `[['1', '1'], '0', ['1', '1', '1'], ['0', '0'], '1']`.

This will work with any values in the list. So if you define `h = ['1', '1', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'A', 'A']`  you'll get `[['1', '1'], ['X', 'X'], 'Y', 'Z', ['A', 'A', 'A']]`.

---

Since you stated that you want to calculate the length of each sequence you don't even have to create an intermediate list.

```
h = ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1']
for element, group in itertools.groupby(h):
    print(f'{len(list(group))} * {element}')
```

The output is

```
2 * 1
1 * 0
3 * 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Keep track of the previous element `p` appended in list l.
Initially, p is set to 0.
If you encounter a "0" in list `h` while traversing, you will directly append "0" to list `l`. and make `p=0` again.

But, If you encounter a "1" in the list `h` while appending it to `l` then, See If the previous element `p` appended in the list was 0 or not so u have 2 cases:

1. if `p==0`: Then u need to create a new list element with "1" i.e. [1].

   `l.append([i])`
2. if `p!=0`: Then u need to append "1" to the last appended list

   `l[-1].append(i)`

Here is the required code with desired Output:

```
l= []
h = ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1']
p=0
for i in h:
    if i == "1":
        if(p==0):
            l.append([i])
            p=1
        else:
            l[-1].append(i)       
    elif i == "0":
      l.append(i)
      p=0
```